# Laravel 5.1 create array variable in .env file for global use

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Actually, I want an array like this in .env file.
I do not have any idea to create an array variable in .env file.

```
 VARIABLE_NAME = [
    [0] => 'Value 1',
    [1] => 'Value 2',
    [2] => 'Value 3',
    ................

];
```

Answer (score 21):

You can't store an array in .env file as the ENV format doesn't support that.

A workaround could be serializing the array to a string of some known format, e.g. comma separated values, and then split it whenever you needed.

This should do the trick:

```
#.env file
VARIABLE_NAME="Value 1,Value 2,Value 3"

#config/app.php
return [
  'VARIABLE_NAME' => explode(',', env('VARIABLE_NAME'))
];
```

Comment: There is work around that allows also associative keys:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/return-array-from-env?page=2

SETTING={"KEY1":"VALUE1","KEY2":"VALUE2"}

$mydata = (array)json_decode(env('SETTING'));